# Are there any coupons/codes/vouchers in the COD: Ghosts PS4 manual?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-ghosts

I'm thinking about buying the game used, and there are a few that sell without the manual.

Does the original games comes with anything extra in the manual, that's not in the [PDF](http://www.callofduty.com/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/ghosts/manuals/Ghosts-Manual-PS4-en.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, with the possible exception of an advertisement for the Season Pass.

There is no detriment to buying it used.

Comment: I know it's not PS4 though for anyones information Xbox comes with 14 day trial and the code for the Free Fall map DLC.